# Finding specific element in large data Array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have JSON array of food items and size of the array is 80000, so i need to find specific element from the large array, and do some comparison.

Comparison is done with the elements from another array of Strings

for now i'm doing it like following,

```
    try (JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("tessdata/fooditems_col_array.json"))) {
    
                reader.beginArray();
                int i = 0;
                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                    String name = reader.nextString();
                    System.out.println(name);
                    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("mackeral")){
                        i++;
                    }
    
                }
                reader.endArray();
                System.out.println("found"+i);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

what is the most efficient way to perform this operation ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there is no order, there is no better way than lenear search.

Comment: If you can ensure the array is sorted (a one-time cost, or low ongoing cost if you keep it sorted as you build it), you can use a binary search algorithm instead of just iterating until you find it.

Comment: @Eklavya, yes, it has no order, so if i sort it what would be the way ?

Comment: As mentioned in the above comment using binary search algorithm after sorting the array once will be the most efficient way

Comment: Depends on the case, sorting will cost roughly O(n log n). But after sorting finding any data takes O(log n). On the other hand, the linear search takes O(n). So it's totally depends on how many times you are searching.

Comment: Thanks for the responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the array is sorted, you can do binary search. If you know that you will need to access it more often, the most efficient ways should be to just insert it into a database like SQLite, MySQL or MongoDB and create an index. If you only start the program once, but search for many entries, a HashMap could do the job too. But for searching something in it once, there is no better way than linear search.